# Clear text but keep image inside <a> hyperlinks using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How i can remove "Product X" and only keep the images using jquery?

```
<span class="product-field-display">
  <a href="/products/product-a-detail" original-title="Product A">
    <img alt="product-a" src="/images/resized/product_a_180x180.png">Product A</a>
</span>
<span class="product-field-display">
  <a href="/products/product-b-detail" original-title="Product B">
    <img alt="product-b" src="/images/resized/product_b_180x180.png">Product B</a>
</span>
```

I tried with:

```
$j('span.product-field-display a').html('');
```

and with:

```
$j('span.product-field-display a').text('');
```

but it gets all cleared and not only the text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grab the image, clear out the anchor, and put the image back:

```
$j('#gkComponent .productdetails-view .product-related-products .product-field-type-R span.product-field-display a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var img = $this.find('img').detach();
    $this.empty().append(img);
});
```

Or do it by removing all text nodes from the anchor via the DOM, leaving the `img` element intact:

```
$j('#gkComponent .productdetails-view .product-related-products .product-field-type-R span.product-field-display a').each(function() {
    var node, nextNode;

    node = this.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        nextNode = node.nextSibling;
        if (node.nodeType === 3) { // 3 = text node
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
        node = nextNode;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Alex: Totally your call, either works. Unless you have tens of thousands of them, there's no need to worry about which is more efficient. The first is shorter. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$('.product-field-display a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html($(this).find('img'));
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/B7eUL/)

Comment: Thanks it works! This is what i ll use because it looks more clear to me but i still have to accept T.J's answer which it was so much faster! I think its too stupid for stack overflow to add this delay on accepting answers and people still trying to give you more answers which they are not needed :S

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery doesn't work very well with text nodes, one way is to handle it in pure JS:

```
$('span.product-field-display a').each(function() {
  var nodes = this.childNodes;

  for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (nodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
      this.removeChild(nodes[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this worked for me

```js
$('#AddToWishList').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt ='Product_ID=1';
  var $this = $(this);
  var img = new Image();
  img.src="images/progress.gif";
  $this.empty().append(img);
  $.post('ajax/add_wish.php', dt, function(data) { 
    $this.empty().append('<i class="fa fa-star"></i>Wishlist');
    $this.attr('class','btn btn-block btn-primary');
    $this.attr('disabled','disabled');    
  });
});
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-block btn-default" href="JavaScript:;;" id="AddToWishList"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>Wishlist</a>
```